# What is the best way to iterate over a python list, excluding certain values and printing out the result

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and have a question:
I have checked similar questions, checked the tutorial *dive into python*, checked the python documentation, googlebinging, similar Stack Overflow questions and a dozen other tutorials.
I have a section of python code that reads a text file containing 20 tweets. I am able to extract these 20 tweets using the following code:

```
with open ('output.txt') as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline,''):   
        Tweets=json.loads(line)             
        data.append(Tweets.get('text'))
    i=0
    while i < len(data):                         
        print data[i] 
        i=i+1
```

The above while loop iterates perfectly and prints out the 20 tweets (lines) from `output.txt`.
However, these 20 lines contain Non-English Character data like `"Los ladillo a los dos, soy maaaala o maloooooooooooo"`, URLs like `"http://t.co/57LdpK"`, the string `"None"` and Photos with a URL like so `"Photo:  http://t.co/kxpaaaaa`(I have edited this for privacy)

I would like to purge the output of this (which is a `list`),  and exclude the following:

1. The `None` entries
2. Anything beginning with the string `"Photo:"`
3. It would be a bonus also if I can exclude non-unicode data

I have tried the following bits of code

1. Using `data.remove("None:")` but I get the error `list.remove(x): x not in list.`
2. Reading the items I do not want into a set and then doing a comparison on the output but no luck.
3. Researching into list comprehensions, but wonder if I am looking at the right solution here.

I am from an Oracle background where there are functions to chop out any wanted/unwanted section of output, so really gone round in circles in the last 2 hours on this. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had to reconstruct your indentation, please do check if it still looks like you wanted it. You already use a `for` loop earlier, why not use a `for` loop to loop over the `data` list instead of using a separate counter? `for` is really a `for each` construct. `for entry in data: print data`.

Comment: You have fetched the values of 'text' keys in your file. You would probably benefit by not fetching only the 'text' of the tweets and appending them to data. There is probably other information in the output.txt file that could help you. Do you know what information you have in output.txt?

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters many thanks for the edit. Just to confirm, the new indentation is still good as I expected. Ok I am just trying your suggestion now.

Comment: @nicholaschris thanks for your tips too, *output.txt* contains a structured tweet, which is a dict that looks something similar to {"created_at":,"id":,"id_str":,"text":,"source":,"truncated":,"in_reply_to_status_id":....} to put it all into context, the entire aim is to perform sentiment analysis on this text field from twitter.

Comment: @Allan.B You could make a conditional to only add the tweets with 'lang' : 'en' ...

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
def legit(string):
    if (string.startswith("Photo:") or "None" in string):
        return False
    else:
        return True

whatyouwant = [x for x in data if legit(x)]
```

I'm not sure if this will work out of the box for your data, but you get the idea.  If you're not familiar, `[x for x in data if legit(x)]` is called a list comprehension

Answer (score 2):

First of all, only add `Tweet.get('text')` if there *is* a text entry:

```
with open ('output.txt') as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline,''):   
        Tweets=json.loads(line)
        if 'text' in Tweets:
            data.append(Tweets['text'])
```

That'll not add `None` entries (`.get()` returns `None` if the `'text'` key is not present in the dictionary).

I'm assuming here that you want to further process the `data` list you are building here. If *not*, you can dispense with the `for entry in data:` loops below and stick to one loop with `if` statements. `Tweets['text']` is the same value as `entry` in the `for entry in data` loops.

Next, you are looping over python `unicode` values, so use [the methods provided on those objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) to filter out what you don't want:

```
for entry in data:
    if not entry.startswith("Photo:"):
        print entry
```

You *can* use a list comprehension here; the following would print all entries too, in one go:

```
print '\n'.join([entry for entry in data if not entry.startswith("Photo:")])
```

In this case that doesn't really buy you much, as you are building one big string just to print it; you may as well just print the individual strings and avoid the string building cost.

Note that **all** your data is Unicode data. What you perhaps wanted is to filter out text that uses codepoints beyond *ASCII* points perhaps. You could use regular expressions to detect that there are codepoints beyond ASCII in your text

```
import re
nonascii = re.compile(ur'[^\x00-0x7f]', re.UNICODE)  # all codepoints beyond 0x7F are non-ascii

for entry in data:
    if entry.startswith("Photo:") or nonascii.search(entry):
        continue  # skip the rest of this iteration, continue to the next
    print entry
```

Short demo of the non-ASCII expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> nonascii = re.compile(ur'[^\x00-\x7f]', re.UNICODE)
>>> nonascii.search(u'All you see is ASCII')
>>> nonascii.search(u'All you see is ASCII plus a little more unicode, like the EM DASH codepoint: \u2014')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1086275e0>
```

Comment: Problem is, the text itself can contain unwanted data. Links etc. He doesn't want those either by the looks of it (thought of something similar at first)

Comment: @Torxed: I was going to add an entry for non-ascii first.

Comment: I see :) And this is why I don't prematurely downvote posts like some people do on SO :P

Comment: @MartijnPieters feedback: by the way the first bit of code worked perfect. Now adding the additional functionality suggested by you and and others to further tidy the data by removing non-ascii characters. Guys, I've learnt alot from all your expertise combined, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open ('output.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        Tweets=json.loads(line)
        if not 'text' in Tweets: continue

        txt = Tweets.get('text')
        if txt.replace('.', '').replace('?','').replace(' ','').isalnum():
            data.append(txt)
            print txt
```

Small and simple.
Basic principle, one loop, if data matches your "OK" criteria add it and print it.

As **Martijn** pointed out, 'text' might not be in all the Tweets data.

---

Regexp replacement for `.replace()` would go something along the lines of: `if re.match('^[\w-\ ]+$', txt) is not None:`  (it will not work for blankspace etc so yea as mentioned below..)

Comment: You get the idea, or do a regexp which would be cleaner, i'm not good enough with regexp to build something descent.

Comment: This will fail as there are entries without `'text'` keys in the data set (which is why `None` is printed).

Comment: Thanks @Torxed much appreciated. Basically you say something similar to what Martijn says.One loop, keep it clean and tidy. I am going to attempt just that. As always I am amazed by the help on Stack overflow!

Comment: You're more than welcome, and i would go with a regexp solution if i were you, but as i mentioned i completely suck at it :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open ('output.txt') as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline,''):   
        Tweets=json.loads(line)             
        data.append(Tweets.get('text'))
        i=0
        while i < len(data):
            # these conditions will skip (continue) over the iterations
            # matching your first two conditions.                         
            if data[i] == None or data[i].startswith("Photo"):
                continue
            print data[i] 
            i=i+1
```

Comment: Is there any reason for which you think indenting 2 spaces is cool?

Comment: I think it is Google's internal style.

Comment: @BenjaminKaiser & all thank you kindly for your suggestions too. Many options to try, I am going to implement and see the best. Much better position than I was 2 hours ago and learnt alot.

Comment: @BenjaminKaiser: It *used* to be Google's internal style, but they've moved up to 4 spaces now too. See http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Indentation They followed where PEP-8 led.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank-you for pointing that out. I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something like the following:

```
# use itertools.ifilter to remove items from a list according to a function
from itertools import ifilter
import re

# write a function to filter out entries you don't want
def my_filter(value):
    if not value or value.startswith('Photo:'):
        return False

    # exclude unwanted chars
    if re.match('[^\x00-\x7F]', value):
        return False

    return True

# Reading the data can be simplified with a list comprehension
with open('output.txt') as fp:
    data = [json.loads(line).get('text') for line in fp]

# do the filtering
data = list(ifilter(my_filter, data))

# print the output
for line in data:
    print line
```

Regarding unicode, assuming you're using python 2.x, the `open` function won't read data as unicode, it'll be read as the `str` type.  You might want to convert it if you know the encoding, or read the file with a given encoding using `codecs.open`.

Comment: thanks, the more the merrier. I had looked at list comprehensions but looks even more manageable now that you've given an example in this context. Will make it a point to learn more on list comprehensions.