# Python: How to loop through a list excluding some numbers belonging to another list?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I need to loop through a list "A" of 100.000 elements. But I need to skip some of them, in particlular I want to skip the elements which are written into another list "B".
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Make a set from `B`, and check if each element is `in B`.

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: `B = set(B); only_in_A = [x for x in A if x not in B]`... Or if you don't care about multiple repeated values in `A`, then convert `A` to a `set`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to iterate over a python list, excluding certain values and printing out the result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548176/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-python-list-excluding-certain-values-and)

Comment: What's best depends on what you mean with "best" (runtime? memory? code niceness?) and the contents of the lists (sizes? sorted?) and the desired iteration order.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a filter:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 2]
list(filter(lambda el: el not in b, a))
# [0, 3, 4]
```

If you need to iterate on the elements, drop the `list` wrapping the filter:

```
for el in filter(lambda el: el not in b, a):
    do_something()
```

Alternatively, the same can be achieved with a list comprehension, which is essentially the same semantically:

```
[el for el in a if el not in b]
# [0, 3, 4]
```

Keep in mind that in both those versions, you'll be performing a linear search on the elements of b.
If that list is pretty long, this might get really slow.
A more efficient method (as suggested in the comments) would be to make b a set rather than a list.
This only requires the elements of b to be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html).

```
bset = set(b)
[el for el in a if el not in bset]
# [0, 3, 4]
```